# Why does sql server consider a function that extracts a value from an xml parameter non-deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, functions, xml

I want to add a computed field that extracts a value from another xml column.

The function looks like this:

```
create or alter function extractValue(@val xml) returns varchar(14)
as 
begin
 return @val.value('(/profile/employeeNumber)[1]', 'varchar(14)')
end
```

When I run this:

```
alter table TableName Add EmployeeNumber as dbo.extractValue(ProfileXML) persisted
```

I get:

> SQL Server Database Error: Computed column 'EmployeeNumber' in table
>   'TableName' cannot be persisted because the column is
>   non-deterministic.

As far as I know a non-deterministic function is a function that can return different values for the same input. In this case if I pass the same xml the value returned is the same.

Also I cannot convert the hard-coded strings in the first and second parameters of the xml value function to parameters to have a 100% dependency on parameters.

Is there any tweak to persist the field? I want to persist it for performance reasons.

If I cannot get this to work somehow, the other option left is to use a trigger and populate the field via the trigger.

Thanks

Comment: Because you could change the function definition without dropping the column, unless you create it with schemabinding. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344620/how-to-mark-an-xquery-expression-as-deterministic-in-order-to-persist-a-comput/61345296#61345296